# Unable to use table having namespace in Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Can someone help me with using a table having namespace using Sequelize.define.

Code is as follow.

```
*connection.define('[Config].[Setting]', {
        SettingId: {
            type: sequelize.STRING,
            primary: true
        },
        Name: sequelize.STRING,
        DataType: sequelize.STRING
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false,
    });*
```

So in the above code Config is namespace of Setting table.

Comment: You have `Config` database and `settings` table?

Comment: no db is icebreaker config is namespace of table

Comment: Have you tried `schema : Config` in sequelize contructor?

Comment: Thanks Shoaib it works